# How to preserve and upgrade SQLITE database during database upgrade

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the requirement to preserve the old data when i upgrade the database in a SQLite database. The old database has records which are important. I want to

- upgrade the database and
- keep the old data and
- append new data

to the database.

Answer (score 4):

this is the simplest possibility i think you have

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
 Log.w("Upgrading" 
 , "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to " + newVersion + "
 , preserving old data");
 customAlterDB(db);
}

private void customAlterDb(SQLiteDatabase db){
        //alter your table(s) here
}
```

just be sure that your new database version is still consistent even with your old-version data in it.